# Show $\bigcup _{i\varepsilon \mathbb{Z}}\left[ i,i+1\right) =\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

*My proof idea.* $(\Rightarrow)$. Let $x\in\bigcup _{i\in \mathbb{Z}}\left[ i,i+1\right)$. We need to show that $x\in\left( -\infty ,\infty \right)$. Actually, is it clear?

$\left( \Leftarrow \right)$. Let $x\in\left( -\infty ,\infty \right)$. We need to show that $x\in\bigcup _{i\in \mathbb{Z}}\left[ i,i+1\right)$. How can I show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the left inclusion is trivial since $[i, i+1) \subset \Bbb R \ \forall i \in \Bbb Z$. Now, for the other inclusion, pick $x \in \Bbb R$, and assume $x > 0$. Then by the Archimedean principle there exists some $n \in \Bbb N : n > x$. Furthermore, since $\Bbb N$ is well-ordered, we can pick the least such $n$. Then $n > x \ge n - 1 \implies x \in [n-1, n)$, and obviously $n-1 \in \Bbb Z$. For $x < 0$ a very similar argument can be made taking $n > - x$ (be careful with half open intervals extremes, though). The case $x=0$ is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

First, for any $i$ we have $[i,i+1) \subset \mathbb{R}$, hence
$\cup_i [i,i+1) \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Now suppose $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then $x \in [\lfloor x \rfloor, \lfloor x \rfloor +1)$. Hence $\mathbb{R} \subset \cup_i [i,i+1)$.

Comment: I am afraid that your proof is cyclic because the definition of the floor function uses the conclusion in this problem.

Comment: It is not cyclic, the existence of the floor function is a straightforward consequence of the Archimedean Principle. In any event, I doubt that the OP is working from the axioms.

Answer (score -1):

$\left( \Leftarrow \right)$. $\forall x \in (-\infty, +\infty)$, always $\exists i \in \mathbb Z$, such that $i \le x < i+1$, thus $x \in [i, i+1)$, thus $x \in \cup_{i\in \mathbb Z}[i,i+1)$. Thus $(-\infty, +\infty) \subset \cup_{i\in \mathbb Z}[i,i+1)$

Comment: You have done nothing but repeated the conclusion to be proved.

Comment: @LiLi I do not agree that I have done nothing. I just did not show the later two steps because I thought it was obvious. I've updated my answer. Can you make sense of it now?

Comment: Why exists $i\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $i\leq x<i+1$? I think the aim of this problem is to help one understand the axioms. I admit it is OBVIOUS. But I think you need to PROVE it.

Comment: @LiLi I do not think so. The whole point here is to prove based on axioms. And now you downvote, because I did not prove an obvious thing? It's nonsense. Look at other answers, any of it strictly proved this? All answers are approaching with the same thing, but mine get 3 downvotes! Do people really think before they act? NO DOUBT, this is a CORRECT proof!

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you so much for your support!

Comment: But I think what you have done is nothing but change a method of expression. I think the essence is to apply the axioms. What can be used are the AXIOMS but not our FEELINGS.

Comment: @LiLi I think copper.hat explain it to you already. I do not think that my my proof is based on feelings. I understand your point, and I know all modern mathematics like you, but I think this proof has a sufficient ground within the context of this question.

Comment: Yeah..But I do not think you have explained the "sufficient ground" clearly. At least not clearly to me.

Comment: @LiLi Anyway, go ahead to downvote. But usually the downvote is not used for not explaining things like that (It's fine if you do not upvote if you think some lower-level discussion is needed, but you downvote only if the answer is bad, and misleading, or a spam)

Comment: I feel sorry if I abused the functions. I downvoted not merely because it is not correct or I could not understand it, but because you behaved like you did not understand the axiom systems or you were not serious about this problem.

Comment: @LiLi Ok, it's fine, everyone has different understanding/assumption when reading a question. My understanding is that given OP asking this question, he should understand those low-level axiom systems, and also he should know that given $x$, there is $i$ and $i+1$ that $x$ lies between. My assumption/feeling is that the OP asked because he was not able to streamline the proof by noticing this point, and use the fact that given $x$ there is $i/(i+1)$, and then link it to the final form of union of the sets.

Comment: I don't agree that he should know "there is $i$ and $i+1$ that $x$ lies between" because this is what he asked us to prove. However, I think one who asks such a kind of question should make it clear that what axioms can be used.

Comment: @LiLi Well, he should know it, as long as he took some very fundamental real analysis course (like some first-year undergrad course), and asking this question is a sign that he took such course.

Comment: By the way, in my opinion, the relation between "there is $i$ and $i+1$ that $x$ lies between" and "$x\in[i,i+1)$"is too trivial. So I assume who asked this question could also be aware of this relation. Anyway, just like what you said, everyone could have different assumptions.

Comment: @LiLi Yea, that is exactly my point: I think he's aware of this relation, but he did not realize to use it here for this proof - that's why in my first version of answer, I just pointed it out, because I think he should be able to figure the rest out with such a hint. (And this is another rule of this site: we prefer hint, and provoke the OP to arrive answer himself if we could, esp. for a simple question like this)